# How to efficiently filter list based on multiple categories on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have a screen which displays list of petrol stations, like this.
[image]

There are 3 dropdowns: the left is for filtering based on brand (Shell, Star, etc), the middle is for sorting based on distance (ascending and descending), and the right is for filtering based on facility (ATM, toilet, etc). If all of the 3 dropdowns show "All", then the original list will be displayed. Otherwise... a few cases.

Filtering "Esso" only:

[image]

Filtering "Esso" which has ATM:

[image]

As you change the values of those dropdowns, the list must be filterend and accordingly. So far, I have finished working on handling the facility dropdown. It has lots of nested if-else blocks which easily confuses me, e.g:

```
 else if (dropdownBrand == "All" && dropdownDistance != "All"){
   if (dropdownDistance == "Near to far"){

     _displayedList = _petrolList;
     _displayedList.sort((a,b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
     _displayedList = _displayedList
         .where((PetrolItem item) => item.facilities.toString().toLowerCase() == dropdownFacilities.toString().toLowerCase())
         .toList();
   }
   else {
     _displayedList = _petrolList;
     _displayedList.sort((a,b) => b.price.compareTo(a.price));
     _displayedList = _displayedList
          .where((PetrolItem item) => item.facilities.toString().toLowerCase() == dropdownFacilities.toString().toLowerCase())
          .toList();
   }
}
else if (dropdownBrand != "All" && dropdownDistance == "All"){
  _displayedList = _petrolList;
  _displayedList = _displayedList
      .where((PetrolItem item) => item.brand.toString().toLowerCase() == dropdownBrand.toString().toLowerCase() && item.facilities.toString().toLowerCase() == dropdownFacilities.toString().toLowerCase())
      .toList();
}
else if (dropdownBrand == "All" && dropdownDistance == "All"){
  _displayedList = _petrolList;
  _displayedList = _displayedList
      .where((PetrolItem item) => item.facilities.toString().toLowerCase() == dropdownFacilities.toString().toLowerCase())
      .toList();
}
```

Full code: [here](https://gist.github.com/anta40/585b64ee294637f0ef20e42ed198a8f3)

How to simplify the sorting and filtering code?

Answer (score 0):

Try like the below :

```
_displayedList = getListByBrand(brand:_selectedBrand)
_displayedList = getListByFacility(facility: _selectedFacility)
_displayedList = getListListByDistance(distance: _selectedDistance)


List<outlet> getListByBrand(String brand) {
    if (brand == '') {

        return _displayedList ;
    } else {
        // Apply your filter here.
        return _filteredList ;

    }

}

List<outlet> getListByFacility(String facility) {
    if (facility == '') {

        return _displayedList ;
    } else {
        // Apply your filter here.
        return _filteredList ;

    }

}

ist<outlet> getListListByDistance(String distance) {
    if (distance == '') {

        return _displayedList ;
    } else {
        // Apply your filter here.
        return _filteredList ;

    }

}
```